# How can we know the size of a dimension?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Measuring extra-dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22542/measuring-extra-dimensions)

I was watching a layman's documentary and it said:

"The 11th dimension is incredibly small, like a long tube about $10^-30m$ in diameter".

How can we know the general sizes of extra dimensions?

Comment: Note that $10^{-30}$ m is smaller than ay tool we currently use can measure.

Comment: I know, so how can we know the sizes of these dimensions? Given that we can't see them

Comment: @ODP: 11 dimention is just the theory no one has yet proved it, hence noone ever measured it