# Do we live in a 4-dimensional space, i.e. a 5-dimensional spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

As far as we know:
If two one-dimensional lines are placed parallel, they need to be on a two-dimensional plane.
If two 2-dimensional planes are placed parallel, they need to be in a 3-dimensional space.
So is our space a 4-dimensional space because we (3-dimensional objects) can be placed parallel? (or am I misunderstanding?)

Comment: An n-dimensional object doesn't have any physical meaning in an n+1 dimensional space. It's a pure abstract.

Comment: How do you propose placing two 3-dimensional objects in parallel?

Comment: @FlatterMann You can certainly have an $n$-dimensional object embedded in $n+1$ dimensions. For example, the plane in 3 spatial dimensions, as said by OP. Could you please clarify the point you're trying to make?

Comment: @DanDan0101 A plane is an abstract. It's not a physical object. The nearest approximation of a plane in three dimensions is a sheet, i.e. a flat object with a thickness that is small compared to its other dimensions. It's still a three dimensional object.

Comment: @FlatterMann Sure, I agree with you, but I think this misses the point of the question.

Comment: The problem with the question is the last sentence. Can 3-dimensional objects be placed in parallel in 4 dimensions? A three dimensional object is not an object in 4 dimensions. It does not have physicality in any operationally conceivable way. If the OP is talking about geometry, then the answer is trivial, but the question does not make sense in a physical context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150994/discussion-between-flattermann-and-dandan0101).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4079/2451

Comment: We are not infinitely extended (like a plane is). Instead of thinking about two 2-dimensional planes, consider instead 2 rectangles (or maybe two identical drawings of a person), which are 2-dimensional objects of limited extent. You can place them in parallel in the way you describe (by sliding them on a 2-dimensional plane) without needing 3-dimensional space. They are just placed next to each other in the plane. So, no, us being able to do the same thing does not imply that space is 4-dimensional.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  The answer appears to be very different from the one linked.  The concept of "parallel" you are thinking of here is actually a 1 dimensional concept used to map 3d objects.  Parallel objects means we can draw 2 parallel lines (1 dimensional) and define a relationship between points of one object and the first line and the corresponding points of the second object and the second line.  We only needed 1d lines, so a 3d space is more than sufficient.  Parallel 3d spaces (requiring 4 dimensions) are hard to intuit because you and I live in 3d.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're a string theorist, we typically consider ourselves to live in **3 spatial dimensions** and 1 time dimension. So, you'll often hear people refer to the 4-dimensional spacetime.